# C++: I get an iterator in one method, how to modify the original list by iterator in another mothod?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a list, I am tring to find a list item by value in one method, in another method to modify this item.
Here is the simplified code:

```
using namespace std;

//find iterator by value
list<int>::iterator get_iterator(list<int> li,int value) {
    list<int>::iterator it;
    for(it = li.begin();it != li.end();it++) {
        if(*it == value) {
            return it;
        }
    }
    return li.end();
}

int main() {
    list<int> num_list;
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++) {
        num_list.push_back(i);
    }
    // print the list
    for(list<int>::iterator it = num_list.begin();it != num_list.end();it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    list<int>::iterator target_it = get_iterator(num_list,10);
    // cout << *target_it <<endl;
    *target_it = 100; // try to modify the original list(num_list) by iterator.

    // print the list again
    for(list<int>::iterator it = num_list.begin();it != num_list.end();it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

**The original list has not been modified**, is there any chance to make it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `get_iterator` function does essentailly the same as [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). so you could just use that instead.

Comment: The code is simplified.  What if the type is not `int` but `struct`, for example `struct a {int id; char name[20]};`, and I only know the id? I don't know how to do it by std::find.

Comment: Then you could use `std::find_if` and pass a lambda function as the third parameter. The lambda function would compare the ids. E.g. `std::find_if(lis.begin(), lis.end(), [=](const struct a& x) { return x.id == id; });` where `lis` is the list and `id` is the variable containing the id you're searching for.

Comment: awesome, I learned many things from this post!, Thanks john, mch and Phantomas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list<int>::iterator get_iterator(list<int> li,int value)` gets the list by value, so it is a copy of the original list.

After returning the iterator, the copy list gets destroyed and so the iterator is invalid. Using it invokes undefined behaviour.

You want to pass the list by reference

```
list<int>::iterator get_iterator(list<int> &li,int value)
                                        //^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is actually right. However your issue comes from the function `get_iterator`. In your current implementation, you're taking the parameter `li` by value, which internally create a copy. Thus the iterator you get belong to a copy of the list in the function main, and not from that list.

You can fix your issue by taking the list by reference by replacing the type of parameter `li` from `list<int> li` to `list<int> &li`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make it a global variable or pass it to the function by reference (prefixing the variable name with &)